# drag object right and left only in swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a label called `date2` and I want to drag him **only** to right or left.
I have got 2 issues - first - I have copied a code by the internet but the Xcode show a bug:

```
@IBOutlet var date2: UILabel!
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch

        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

        date2.center = location
    }
```

The second thing is - that the code is to move the label anywhere and not only to the right and left.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
@IBOutlet var date2: UILabel!

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch

    var location = date2.center
    location.x = touch.locationInView(self.view).x

    date2.center = location
}
```

I think it solves ur both issues.

Comment: It gives me the same error:         `method does not override any method from its superclass`

Comment: The method signature changed on touches began in swift 2, use the autocomplete to help rewrite it